# sed command to replace a string from one file with entire contents of another file

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk

I want to write a sed (or awk) command to replace a string from one file with the entire contents of another file. Note that second file from which I want to get the content has more than one line. I tried this:

```
sed -e "s/PLACEHOLDER/$(sed 's:/:\\/:g' TestOutput.txt)/" SQLInput.txt
```

but got an error saying `sed: -e expression #1, char 22: unterminated 's' command`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try

```
sed -i '/PLACEHOLDER/ r TestOutput.txt' SQLInput.txt
```

where

- `-i` edit in place
- `/PLACEHOLDER/` search for pattern
- `r TestOutput.txt` read file

note that  `/PLACEHOLDER/` is not deleted.

to have it deleted

```
sed -i -e '/PLACEHOLDER/ r TestOutput.txt' -e s/PLACEHOLDER// SQLInput.txt
```

where

- `-e /PLACEHOLDER/d` will delete entire line with PLACEHOLDER
- `-e s/PLACEHOLDER//` will delete PLACEHOLDER string

Comment: I want the PLACEHOLDER to be deleted. Whats the change I should make?

Comment: Thats deleting entire line containing PLACEHOLDER string. I want to replace only word PLACEHOLDER with contant from second file. Please let me know

Comment: you can also use `//d` and `s///` to avoid repeating the regexp

Answer (score 0):

A sed code is simpler in this case, but since there's also an awk tag on this question:

```
awk 'function readfile (file) { getline var < file ; return var }
     BEGIN { RS="^$" }; gsub(/PLACEHOLDER/,readfile("TestOutput.txt"))
' SQLInput.txt
```

Comment: (assumes GNU `awk` or `mawk` for the regexp RS. Most other `awk` implementations will split on `^` characters there).