# sed command to replace a word from one file with entire line of another file

Tags: sed, replace, line

I want to use the sed command (or something that works) to replace a word in a template file with a word in a line of another file.

As an example I have a file with a list of words, each word is in a different line and I want to use sed to take the first word (which is in the first line) and put it in another file where the word "value1" is written. I thought that with [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/191219/sed-command-to-replace-a-string-from-one-file-with-entire-contents-of-another-fi) post I could be able to do it, but I can't figure it out.

Graphic example:

File A:

```
Maria
Albert
Toni
Henry
Tom
```

File B:

```
The name of the student is: value1
```

Expected output for line 3:

```
The name of the student is: Toni
```

I want to be able to move one of the names from file A to file B where value1 is placed. And I want to do it multiple times.

Comment: post a sample input content and expected result

Comment: I just edited the question with an example input and output.

Comment: Is your template always a single line?

Comment: Does `value1` always occur one and only one time in the template?

Comment: yes, value1 occurs only 1 time, I will use different value names for every word I have to replace.

Comment: The template is not always a single line, it was just for the example. The template file has multiple lines with multiple values to replace from the listing file A.

Comment: You mean there's potentially a `value2`, `value3`... ? How are the corresponding entries stored in fileA?

Comment: yes, there will be value2, value3, valueN... The entries are stored line by line, like a list.

Comment: @EnriqueTorellóPerelló, and how should `value1, value2 and value3` be distributed along 5 input lines?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest They can be distributed anywhere in the text, I just need to take a word from the list (file A) and substitute it for one of the selected values in file B.

Comment: Please expand your example to cover several `value`s and lines. I still don't understand why `value1` is douns on line 3.

Comment: Why not use `printf` formats instead of your own format? Example `' The name of the student is %s'`, then you would not need to do the search and replace of value1 which @Stéphane Chazelas does in his perl script.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `perl`:

```
perl -ne '
  BEGIN{
    local $/ = undef;
    $template = <STDIN>; # slurp file B in
  }
  chomp;
  print $template =~ s/\bvalue1\b/$_/gr' fileA < fileB
```

If your version of `perl` is too old to support the `r` substitute flag, you can use a temporary variable:

```
perl -ne '
  BEGIN{
    local $/ = undef;
    $template = <STDIN>; # slurp file B in
  }
  chomp;
  ($out = $template) =~ s/\bvalue1\b/$_/g;
  print $out' fileA < fileB
```

Comment: It gives me a compilation error and I never used perl... :/ Any suggestions?

Comment: @EnriqueTorellóPerelló, possibly, you have an old version of `perl` before the `r` flag was added.

Comment: where do I specify the line from file A to replace in file B? 
I suppose that value1 is the value from file B to be replaced. Right?

Comment: @EnriqueTorellóPerelló, that answer answers your question as currently stated in the body of your question, the additional comments to your question seem to suggest a different question. I've given up trying to guess what you actually want to do. You should edit your question with a more relevant example.