# sed: -e expression #1, char 73: unterminated `s' command

Tags: shell-script, shell, sed, github

I'm very new to SH and development and I'm blundering my way through the code one error at a time.

I've come across this error now that I can not get to the bottom of. Any help would be great!

I am running a sh script in GitHub Actions and am receiving this error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 73: unterminated `s' command
```

Here's my code:

```
SPECTESTSFILE='manifest/specifictests.xml'
  cat $SPECTESTSFILE

  BUILDXML_TEMPLATE_FILE='buildFiles/buildrunspecifictests.template.xml'
  SPECTESTS="$(cat $SPECTESTSFILE)"
  echo "Specified Tests: "
  echo $SPECTESTS
  sed -i "s|<runTest><\/runTest>|$SPECTESTS|g" $BUILDXML_TEMPLATE_FILE
```

In my manifest/specifictests.xml file, I have a list of RunTests with new lines

```
<runTest>...</runTest>
<runTest>....</runTest>
```

and I want to insert this list into the buildFiles/buildrunspecifictests.template.xml file

```
<deploy>
    <runTest></runTest>
</deploy>
```

Eventually, I want the file to look like this:

```
<deploy>
   <runTest>...</runTest>
   <runTest>....</runTest>
</deploy>
```

What I've found is that if there are no newlines in the manifest/specifictests.xml file then it works but this doesn't allow me much freedom for the user's using it or eventually automating the creation of this file elsewhere.

Does anyone know a fix?

Comment: Relating https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/32907/117549

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you've slurped the entire contents of the file 'manifest/specifictests.xml' into the variable SPECTESTS, and you're instructing `sed` to search through the file 'buildFiles/buildrunspecifictests.template.xml' and replace every occurence of the string "<runTest></runTest>" with the entire contents of SPECTESTS.

As you've noticed, this is highly liable to break if there are any special characters in specifictests.xml. In particular, the newlines in $SPECTESTS are interrupting the middle of the "s" command, as the error says; the newlines would have to be escaped for sed to keep reading the command.

It sounds like all you actually want to do is prepend "<deploy>" and append "</deploy>" to the contents of specifictests.xml? Is that right?

In which case, you could just do

`{ echo "<deploy>"; cat "$SPECTESTSFILE"; echo "</deploy>"; } > "$BUILDXML_TEMPLATE_FILE"`

If that won't work, then to specifically work around newlines in `$SPECTESTS`, you can replace them with something else before feeding it to sed, and then turn them back into newlines after sed is done, like this:

```
SPECTESTS="$(tr '\n' '\r' < $SPECTESTSFILE)"
sed "s|<runTest><\/runTest>|$SPECTESTS|g" $BUILDXML_TEMPLATE_FILE | tr '\r' '\n'
```

This puts the result on standard output, not back into buildrunspecifictests.template.xml. (But it seems like you might want the result in a different file anyway, otherwise you'll break future substitutions.)

This is still susceptible to other problematic characters showing up in $SPECTESTS, though, like |, &, or \.

You can try the solutions at [sed command to replace a string from one file with entire contents of another file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/191219/sed-command-to-replace-a-string-from-one-file-with-entire-contents-of-another-fi).

Comment: Thanks so much @NickMatteo. That worked a treat!